# Add horizontal to seaborn countplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have several seaborn bar plot as below, and I would like to add horizontal lines above each set of bars. I know the y coordinates, but how can I automatically get the xmin and ymin range without needing to look at them manually?

```
sns.countplot(x="class", hue="who", kind="bar", data=titanic)
plt.hlines(y=30, xmin=-0.5, xmax=0.5, color='black', alpha=0.4)
plt.hlines(y=50, xmin=0.6, xmax=1.5, color='black', alpha=0.4)
plt.hlines(y=200, xmin=1.5, xmax=2.5, color='black', alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: The bars should extent from `i-0.4` to `i+0.4` with `i` being the integer numbers from `0` to `n-1` (`n` being the number of groups).

Comment: Can't you take the individual `x` value and subtract and add half the width of the bar to get the lower and upper bounds as `xmin` and `xmax`, respectively? Without looking at your data and what you want, it's like shooting arrows in the dark